# How do i edit the light spread on small scene? Or how do you increase the scale without ruining animation?

Tags: transforms, lighting, scene

I made a small scene without realizing it. I already animate everything when i realized i made my scene too small, and now whenever i add light, it spread further than i wanted. what value do i edit to decrease this? or is there a way for me to increase the scene scale without ruining the animation?

for example, i added a backlight to my car[image]
and it spread until the inside of the car, this doesnt happen on previous scene, where the scale of the scene is bigger[image]
even when i added a new light and put the value to really low, it really spread so far[image]
what value do i edit to decrease this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For EEVEE it is ok to set the light *radius* to 0. From your screenshot, I don't see that it is an issue, so thy limit light distance.

You can limit the light by setting *custom distance*, which limits light rays by this distance.

[image]

Comment: i turned down the radius, and i crank down the power to really really low. Like uW low(i didnt even know blender can do that)., That seems to work. thanks